# Setup a led that blinks via php server

Tags: raspbian, gpio, server, led

I wanted to blink or just lit up an LED on my Pi GPIO pin via a server/website.

I've the resources like Pi, LED, php server etc.

I just don't know how to code to connect my Pi to server and control GPIO pin using server commands, help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the php command [`shell_exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to execute a script or bash command which allows you to access the GPIO Pins.
I would suggest writing a python script which takes input parameters and manages the turning on/off accordingly.

Then, from php, you would call this script using (for example) `shell_exec("sudo /usr/bin/python /path/to/script.py on 50");`

You will need root access to use the GPIO (that's why there's the sudo there), one idea to do this is is allowing this one file to be executed without password for the user www-data:
Edit /etc/sudoers as root (using the command `visudo`) and add

```
pi raspberry = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/python /path/to/script
```

at the end for user pi on host raspberry.

On how to access the GPIO via python, take a look [here](http://openmicros.org/index.php/articles/94-ciseco-product-documentation/raspberry-pi/217-getting-started-with-raspberry-pi-gpio-and-python).
You can read the command line parameters using

```
import sys
parameterone = sys.argv[1] #sys.argv[0] will always be the filename
```

If you want continous blinking and turning it off again via the php webinterface, it's probably easiest to have a configuration file somewhere, and have the python file (with an infinite loop) run at startup and check the file every second. From php, alter the contents of the file to control what the python script does.

I hope this helps,
have fun experimenting!